# How to create list filled with methods in Java and iterate over it (using methods)

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I want to be able to create list (collection, array) filled with my own methods and in each step of iteration call the method. What's the best solution for this?

I want something like this:

```
List a = new List();
a.add(myCustomMethod1());
a.add(myCustomMethod2());

Object o = new Object();

for (Method m : a){
    m(o);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you can do this with reflection by making a list of `Method` objects. However, an easier way is to define an interface for objects that have a method that takes an `Object` argument:

```
public interface MethodRunner {
    public void run(Object arg);
}

List<MethodRunner> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new MethodRunner() {
    @Override
    public void run(Object arg) {
        myCustomMethod1(arg);
    }
});
a.add(new MethodRunner() {
    @Override
    public void run(Object arg) {
        myCustomMethod2(arg);
    }
});

Object o = new Object();

for (MethodRunner mr : a) {
    mr.run(o);
}
```

Comment: For what it can be used?

Comment: @АлександрГончаренко - This kind of thing is often used to implement a listener or observer pattern. It can also be used to implement a dispatch table (although then you probably wouldn't iterate through the list, but rather retrieve an element by index). There are probably other uses as well; this was just off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Interface solution seems to be good and easy but what if each method have different arguments? For example myCustomMethod1(int, int), myCustomMethod2(String, double) and so on? Can i customize run method somehow? Or is better to use reflection then?

Comment: @user3049167 - In that scenario, how would you even know what arguments to pass in your loop? Reflection is going to have the same problem: how will you construct the argument array?

Comment: @TedHopp What I actually need to do is: I need to create graph drawing generation history, list of actions like "Create Vertex there", "Draw order from Vertex x to Vertex y", "Move Vertex from loc x to loc y" and so on.. Also I need to step back and forward in my history. So I though that the best solution will be list of methods which I could iterate over. I do need iterate over the list because of ongoing drawing animation, I need to call the method, sleep thread, next cycle, call method, sleep thread and so on..

Comment: @user3049167 - Take a look at the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). I think it's just what you're looking for. You can search the web for "java command pattern" and get lots of examples and case studies of how to implement it. (It's basically a generalization of my answer.)

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8 and above you can create a List of Functional Interfaces to store the methods, as the following example shows:

```
// Create a list of Consumer
List<Consumer<String>> methodList= new ArrayList<>();

// Store the methods in the list
methodList.add(p -> method1(p));
methodList.add(p -> method2(p));
methodList.add(p -> method3(p));
methodList.forEach(f -> f.accept("Hello"));
```

Functions with no arguments you can use Runnable:

```
List<Runnable> methods = new ArrayList<>();
methods.add(() -> method1());
methods.add(() -> method2());
methods.add(() -> method3());
methods.forEach(f -> f.run());
```

Comment: What if you want to use void, no-arg methods? Just use raw Consumer class?