# Create a list that contains methods and after execute then in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a list that contains methods, and after I add some methods I want to execute them, is this possible?

Thank you,

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203660/how-to-create-list-filled-with-methods-in-java-and-iterate-over-it-using-method

Answer (score 0):

If your methods have no arguments, consider using [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) to wrap your methods. `Runnable` has no return value, and `Callable` has a return value.

If your methods need some arguments, check out the interfaces defined in [`java.util.function`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/package-summary), such as [`Function`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Function).

Also, you can just define your own interfaces as you need.